# Define time period in database for analyses

Tags: django, datetime

I want to store timeseries in a database. The values of these timeseries are usually defined for a certain period, for example:

- country population in 2014, 2015, 2016, etc.
- number of houses in country in 2014, 2015, 2016

I want to combine the data of these varabiales to be able to do some statstics, so housing vs population. This is only possible if I make sure the time periods are exactly the same. The periods are usually on a per year/quarter/month basis. How to best store these values such that I can later compare them?

I currently use start_date (datetime) and end_date (datetime), which obviously works but needs a good GUI to prevent that one person enters for example:

```
start = 1-1-2016 & end = 31-12=2016
```

while another would enter:

```
start = 1-1-2016 & end = 1-1=2017
```

I think it would be a good idea to keep the freedom of defining the period with the user but help them in defining the right thing. How would you suggest to do this?

BTW: I work with Django so my current model has the following two fields:

```
period_start = models.DateField(null=False)
period_end = models.DateField(null=False)
```

**Edit 8-5-2018 10:32: added some information on storing data**
Some extra information for added clarity:
I store my data in two tables: (1) the variable definition and (2) the values.
Variable defintion looks roughly like this:

```
class VarDef(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=False)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)


class VarValue(models.Model):
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=60, decimal_places=20, null=False)
    var = models.ForeignKey(VarDef, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False,
                             related_name='var_values')
    period_start = models.DateField(null=False)
    period_end = models.DateField(null=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer since I don't have your full code(models, views etc). But keep in mind that you can query django `datetime` fields using [`lt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#lt) and [`gt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#gt) like this:

```
import datetime

# user input from your view, I hardcoded just for the sake of the example
start_date = datetime.date(2005, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2005, 3, 31)

house_data = HousesData.objects.filter(period_start__gt=start_date, period_end__lt=end_date)).all()
country_data = CountryData.objects.filter(period_start__gt=start_date, period_end__lt=end_date)).all()

# Do the rest of your calculation
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have added some information to clarify my database structure a bit. The problem lies in that I want to compare for example housing vs population in a graph. In order to do this I need these variables to be related to a same time period, however I do als want to keep the option of allowing people to define different periods (for example months) in case a variable is only available in different periods.